# ipad resolution in xcode's storyboard

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I'm doing an ipad app and I realize I have to take care of 2 different resolutions
newer ipad: 2048-by-1536
older ipad: 1024-by-768 resolution

the storyboard displays the older ipad version
is the application going to scale itself ? I'm guessing no.. so how would I go about increasing the resolution and also seeing the 'bigger' one on the storyboard so I know how the app will look?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have to see it - you will just have to have images that have the prefix '2x-', as the resolution is doubled.

Answer (score 0):

All iPads are 1024 points by 768 points just like all iPhones are 320 points wide. The iPhone 5 mucks things up but that is why we now have Autolayout. Retina iPhone and iPads have 4 pixels per point. This way the storyboard is the same for all iPads what do have to do is provide different artwork if you have an image view in your story board that is 44 x 44 you need two png files one 44 x 44 and one 88 x 88. If the 44 x 44 image is named art.png then the 88 x 88 image should be art@2x.png and in your storyboard you specify just art. iOS will select the correct image file for you.

See **Points Versus Pixels** in the View **Programming Guide for iOS**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW1

See **Supporting High-Resolution Screens In Views** in the **Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW1